# Not picking the script tag condition in DOM

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Not picking the condition when a particular class is available in DOM. Need to enable the below script only when the availablediv class is available in DOM. But this condition is not picking even when the availablediv class is present in the DOM.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
if($('.availablediv').length > 0){
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">.data {
      width: 5%;
}
    .presalesDiv .callPlans h3 {
font-size: 15px !important;
}   
.handsetDiv .callPlans p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
.upfront ul li {
    display: block;
}</style>');

} 
});
</script>
```

Below is the angular ng-if condition to display a div and the condition is working fine.

```
<div class="availablediv" ng-if="data.cluster_desc_count > 0">
                                        <div ng-if="data.cluster_scode">

                                            <ul>
                                                <li>{{data.clusterData}}</li>
                                                <li>{{data.clusterSpeed}}</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to modify h3 tag font size from particular div? If yes then same thing you can achieve by angular

Comment: I want to modify the style of other div as well when the availablediv class is present in DOM

Comment: On what condition or when 'availablediv ' class will be present in DOM

Comment: ng-if="data.cluster_desc_count > 0" - based on this condition. I have mentioned in the div itself

Comment: try like <div ng-style="data.cluster_desc_count > 0 && {'font-size':'15px'}"> </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Do not use angular mix with jquery. That solution will make some confusion. Because angular and jquery is different bind to DOM.
>
>    So when document ready, maybe the div `.availablediv` will be not
>      available
> 2. Do not use append to head. That make your code very bad

If you want to watch element and add css, I suggest you use:

## **1. Use $rootScope to add class to body**

```js
scope.$watch('data.cluster_desc_count', function(value) {
       if (value > 0) {
          $rootScope.isClusterDescCount = true;
       } else {
          $rootScope.isClusterDescCount = false;
       }
    });
```

and use `$rootScope.isClusterDescCount` to add class to body.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-class="{isClusterDescCount: 'is-have-cluster'}">
```

And your css will be

```css
body.is-have-cluster .presalesDiv .callPlans h3 {
font-size: 15px !important;
}   
body.is-have-cluster .handsetDiv .callPlans p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
body.is-have-cluster .upfront ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

## **2. You can use jquery to add class to body like**

```js
scope.$watch('data.cluster_desc_count', function(value) {
   if (value > 0) {
      $('body').addClass('is-have-cluster');
   } else {
      $('body').removeClass('is-have-cluster');
   }
});
```

**The css will be the same**

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can u plz tell me how to use $rootScope.isClusterDescCount to add class to body.